# How to switch back to my choose language Activity when I press the exit button?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

i need help my manifest launcher Activity is LanguageChooseActivity.java, i used shared preferences for when user chose language he dissmiss LanguageChooseActivity and entering in mainActivity directly after start the application but in main Activity i have exit button and when user will press exit button he should back to LanguageChooseActivity to choose again language. Please help to do this.

here is my code:
LanguageChooseActivity

````
 private TextView rusVersion;
 private TextView engVersion;
 private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
 private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
 private boolean launchedEng;
 private boolean launchedRus;


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_language_choose);




         afterChoseLanguage();




     rusVersion = findViewById(R.id.rus_version);
     rusVersion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             if(rusVersion.isPressed()){
                 editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                 editor.putBoolean("launchedRus", true);
                 editor.apply();

             }
             startActivity(new Intent(LanguageChooseActivity.this,RusMainMenuActivity.class));

         }
     });

     engVersion = findViewById(R.id.eng_version);
     engVersion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            if(engVersion.isPressed()){
                editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("launchedEng", true);
                editor.apply();

         }
             startActivity(new Intent(LanguageChooseActivity.this,EngMainMenuActivity.class));

         }
     });

 }

 public void afterChoseLanguage(){
     sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     launchedEng = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("launchedEng",false);
     launchedRus = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("launchedRus",false);
     if(launchedEng){
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, EngMainMenuActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
     } else if (launchedRus){
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, RusMainMenuActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
 }
} ```

and MainMenuActivity:

 ``` FrameLayout layout;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
     MainActivity.scale =(float) dm.widthPixels / 1080f;
     MainActivity.dm = dm;

     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

     layout = new FrameLayout(this);
     layout.setBackgroundColor(ResourceColors.colorWhite);
     setContentView(layout);

     design();

 }

 private void design(){

     Bitmap logoMain = getBitmapFromAsset(this,"logo_Main.png");
     logoMain = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(logoMain,(int)(480*MainActivity.scale),(int)(158*MainActivity.scale), false);
     ImageView iLogoMain = new ImageView(this);
     iLogoMain.setImageBitmap(logoMain);
     iLogoMain.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int)(480*MainActivity.scale),(int)(158*MainActivity.scale)));
     iLogoMain.setX(MainActivity.dm.widthPixels/2 - logoMain.getWidth()/2);
     iLogoMain.setY(80*MainActivity.scale);

     layout.addView(iLogoMain);

     for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
         Bitmap iconRus = getBitmapFromAsset(this, "iconMainMenu/ru_" + (i + 1) + ".png");
         iconRus = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(iconRus, (int) (238 * MainActivity.scale), (int) (238 * MainActivity.scale*(iconRus.getHeight()/(float)iconRus.getWidth())), false);
         ImageView iIcon = new ImageView(this);
         iIcon.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(iconRus.getWidth(), iconRus.getHeight()));
         iIcon.setImageBitmap(iconRus);
         iIcon.setX(55 * MainActivity.scale + (244 * (i % 4))* MainActivity.scale);
         iIcon.setY(390 * MainActivity.scale + (277 * (i / 4))* MainActivity.scale);
         iIcon.setId(100+i);


iIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

                 if (v.getId() == 119) {


                     }



             }
         });


         layout.addView(iIcon);
     }

 }

 public static Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(Context context, String filePath) {
     AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

     InputStream istr;
     Bitmap bitmap = null;
     try {
         istr = assetManager.open(filePath);
         bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
     } catch (IOException e) {
         // handle exception
     }

     return bitmap;
 }


}
````

Answer (score 0):

if I'm understanding your issue correctly, you have already used the answer in your code... have a method in the onClick for your exit button to start another activity.

```
public void btnExit (View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LanguageChooseActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

If you have certain things you'd like to set depending on the screen you came from, you can pass extra info along with the intent call. Just insert the code between the Intent definition and the startActivity call.

```
intent.putExtra("STRING_NAME", VALUE_UNDEFINED); // use "" on the value if sending a string else, don't
```

then when your LanguageChooseActivity starts up again, you can find that info with the following (here you need to define the sent variable type)

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

if (intent.getStringExtra("STRING_NAME").equals("VALUE")) { 
// or (intent.getIntExtra("STRING_NAME") == 0) etc

    // do work

}
```